# Can I do full server side rendering but only partial client side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, reactjs.net

I'm working on an website, that uses both AngularJS and ReactJS to handle different components of the site (for example shopping cart, category tree and so on). The reason we are in a mixed environment is that we started out with Angular, but have since come to favor React. The plan is to migrate all Angular stuff to React.

The problem we're facing right now is that we have product pages that have tabs that contain loads of data. With Angular, you just render it server side in ASP.NET as usual, then an Angular Directive kicks in client side and the tabs are clickable.
What we think we want to do now, is to have ReactJS.NET (or only ASP.NET?) render the tabs server side (with all the data), but to not pass the data to the client side implementation, but instead act more like a directive and only take client side control of the tabs.

Is this at all possible, or are we going to have to pass all the data to the client side script anyways?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, you only want to render the data for the visible tab and not the ones you havent clicked on yet? Then just pass the data you want to render on the server side to the html helper, and let react take over and ajax load the non-visible tabs on the client side. Is this what you are looking for? i can put that in an answer for you.

Comment: I want to render data for 3 out of 5 tabs on the server side. But I do not want to pass that data to the client side rendering, since the size of the HTML sent to the client gets a lot larger. Example of how it looks right now with angular tabs; https://www.inet.se/produkt/6607915/ (the tabs on the middle of the page, "Specifikation", "Mer info", "Recensioner" and so on...)